# search one array with max value of another array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

!I am trying to search one array with the associated value of the other array. Keep in mind that both arrays will always be of equal size. This is how I am trying to do it below:

```
y = max(Intensity1)
print y
x = Frequency1[y]
plot([x], [y], 'v', color='red', ms=10)
text(x, y, "({:0.2f}, {:0.2f})".format(x, y))
```

However, this yields the result of jumping to the maximum value of storing the max value in my frequency array. For the visual, I am essentially trying to plot the frequency at which the maximum magnitude occurs as shown in the picture below. Thinking about my code above, I see it is trying to plot the -26 position in the array, but I want it to search for the same spot where y is at a maximum.

[image: Plot for visual]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `max`, you'll want to use [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to get the *index* of the maximum value in `Intensity1` rather than the value.

```
maxind = np.argmax(Intensity1)
x = Frequency[maxind]

plot(x, Intensity1[maxind], 'v', color='red', ms=10)
```

Comment: I apologize for that, you answered pretty quick and it said I had to wait 7 mins and I ended up forgetting. Thank you again!